# Unable to add 2 associative arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to add 2 associative arrays, but the new array only comes with an index for the second array.

This is what I am doing

```
$array = ['name' => 'address', 'value' => 'us'];
    $arr = ['name' => 'joe', 'value' => 'doe'];

    $arr[] = $array;
```

This is the result

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "joe"
  "value" => "doe"
  0 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I am expecting something like this

```
 array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▶]
      1 => array:2 [▶]
    ]
```

As you can see, there is no index for the first array, thus making the count 3 instead of 2. Please how do I fix this?

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to do and what is the result you expect

Comment: The code does what is supposed to do. If you actually want to merge the two arrays you should use `array_merge`: `$combined = array_merge($array, $arr);`

Comment: did you try `array_merge()` ?

Comment: array_merge returns just one array since the 2 arrays have similar keys @Timo

Comment: @GiacomoM Look at the end result, it is supposed to be 2 arrays but I have 3.

Comment: @radioactive I still don't understand what you need. Please edit your answer to write the expect array.

Comment: @GiacomoM I have done that.

Comment: I think what we are trying to ask is : what is your desired output. That is very unclear at the moment. Do you want to preserve all the keys, do you want to replace the values of the keys when combining? There are so many directions and your current question is unclear with your desired result and what is going wrong.

Comment: try this and see what you get `$result = array_merge($array1, $array2); print_r($result);` you have another choice to use foreach like `foreach($array_merge_result as $key => $value)`

Comment: I get this ```array:2 [▼
  "name" => "address"
  "value" => "us"
]``` It has removed the first array.

Comment: @izk I don't what to replace the keys. And that's what array_merge() does. See my last comment.

Comment: Then look at Giacomo M his answer, but beware for duplicate named keys.

Answer (score 2):

Just create another array and add the 2 arrays to it:

```
$newAr = [];
$newAr[] = $array;
$newAr[] = $arr;
var_dump($newAr);
```